# 4chan's API: How to Loop through json decoded array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, loops

I'm trying to get all the **.wembs** and **.gifs** url from **4chan/wsg/** board so I can download it to my server. I'm having trouble looping through json decoded array in PHP.

Here's my PHP `/threads_update.php` :

```
<?php
$jsonfile = file_get_contents('./threads.json');
$json = json_decode($jsonfile, true);

for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++)
{
  for($x = 0; $x < count($json); $x++)
  {
    $empatch = $json[$i]['threads'][$x]['no'];
    $webmslinks[$x] = 'https://a.4cdn.org/wsg/thread/'.$empatch.'.json';

    echo $i.'-'.$x.' '.'<a href='.$webmslinks[$x].' target="_blank>'.$webmslinks[$x].'</a><br>';
  }
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>'; #printing json decoded array in a nice way
?>
```

in `/threads_update.php`, I'm trying to get all the links to the jsons of all the threads in **4chan/WSG** board so I can get the detail on the posts. If I managed to get all the links, I want to cronjob it to download every * minute to my server so it updates the json.

I practiced a bit on getting the .wembs and .gifs link from the `catalog.json` of 4chan. here's the PHP code `/download_webm.php`

```
<?php
$jsonfile = file_get_contents('./catalog.json');
$json = json_decode($jsonfile, true);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($json); $i++)
{
  for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($json); $x++)
  {
$empatwebm = $json[$i]['threads'][$x]['tim'];
$empatext = $json[$i]['threads'][$x]['ext'];

$webmslinks[$x] = 'http://i.4cdn.org/wsg/'.$empatwebm.$empatext;
echo $i.'-'.$x.' '.'<a href='.$webmslinks[$x].' target="_blank>'.$webmslinks[$x].'</a><br>';
  }
}

#echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

I want to focus on the problem in `/threads_update.php` though, here's the json decoded array I'm using in `/threads_update.php (threads.json)` I cut it a bit because it's too long:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [page] => 1
            [threads] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 247727
                            [last_modified] => 1422731400
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915253
                            [last_modified] => 1453541378
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 914600
                            [last_modified] => 1453541285
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 914648
                            [last_modified] => 1453541160
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915256
                            [last_modified] => 1453541160
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 897749
                            [last_modified] => 1453540855
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 859722
                            [last_modified] => 1453540665
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915689
                            [last_modified] => 1453540443
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915791
                            [last_modified] => 1453540122
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 908252
                            [last_modified] => 1453540105
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 840187
                            [last_modified] => 1453539750
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 869373
                            [last_modified] => 1453539744
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 912342
                            [last_modified] => 1453539519
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 891852
                            [last_modified] => 1453539003
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 888763
                            [last_modified] => 1453538876
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [page] => 2
            [threads] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 873565
                            [last_modified] => 1453538275
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 892015
                            [last_modified] => 1453537537
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 838897
                            [last_modified] => 1453536675
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 892915
                            [last_modified] => 1453536388
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 909050
                            [last_modified] => 1453536039
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 910942
                            [last_modified] => 1453535407
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 882013
                            [last_modified] => 1453535284
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 848161
                            [last_modified] => 1453535096
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 873593
                            [last_modified] => 1453534602
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 878501
                            [last_modified] => 1453534316
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 910000
                            [last_modified] => 1453534025
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 880261
                            [last_modified] => 1453533807
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915089
                            [last_modified] => 1453533162
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 878873
                            [last_modified] => 1453532816
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 870501
                            [last_modified] => 1453532749
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [page] => 3
            [threads] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915195
                            [last_modified] => 1453532318
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 914909
                            [last_modified] => 1453531117
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 903535
                            [last_modified] => 1453529930
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 908885
                            [last_modified] => 1453529620
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 889312
                            [last_modified] => 1453529423
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915043
                            [last_modified] => 1453529897
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 879280
                            [last_modified] => 1453528792
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 879632
                            [last_modified] => 1453528350
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 913957
                            [last_modified] => 1453528312
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 896705
                            [last_modified] => 1453528267
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 847720
                            [last_modified] => 1453528237
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 838871
                            [last_modified] => 1453528084
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 866201
                            [last_modified] => 1453527850
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 913175
                            [last_modified] => 1453526674
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 833726
                            [last_modified] => 1453526453
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [page] => 4
            [threads] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 904445
                            [last_modified] => 1453525838
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 914580
                            [last_modified] => 1453524490
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 845312
                            [last_modified] => 1453522034
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 899118
                            [last_modified] => 1453521816
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 912517
                            [last_modified] => 1453521372
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 885270
                            [last_modified] => 1453520982
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 913473
                            [last_modified] => 1453520859
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 909015
                            [last_modified] => 1453519499
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 915270
                            [last_modified] => 1453518011
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 867625
                            [last_modified] => 1453517740
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 884229
                            [last_modified] => 1453515954
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 902461
                            [last_modified] => 1453514881
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 796602
                            [last_modified] => 1453514879
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 823926
                            [last_modified] => 1453514458
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 907820
                            [last_modified] => 1453513381
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [page] => 5
            [threads] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 748132
                            [last_modified] => 1453511379
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 907219
                            [last_modified] => 1453510720
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 890615
                            [last_modified] => 1453508766
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 728826
                            [last_modified] => 1453508251
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 770452
                            [last_modified] => 1453507296
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 891223
                            [last_modified] => 1453506455
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 884923
                            [last_modified] => 1453505426
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 903103
                            [last_modified] => 1453505232
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 897296
                            [last_modified] => 1453504416
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 904456
                            [last_modified] => 1453503832
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 455445
                            [last_modified] => 1453503725
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 907417
                            [last_modified] => 1453503134
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 906474
                            [last_modified] => 1453502455
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 913944
                            [last_modified] => 1453501859
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 904009
                            [last_modified] => 1453500314
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [page] => 6
            [threads] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 908709
                            [last_modified] => 1453497962
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 909604
                            [last_modified] => 1453497092
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 867205
                            [last_modified] => 1453497003
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 906638
                            [last_modified] => 1453495282
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 903238
                            [last_modified] => 1453494874
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 914875
                            [last_modified] => 1453494475
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 891512
                            [last_modified] => 1453493842
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 885175
                            [last_modified] => 1453489777
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 889144
                            [last_modified] => 1453487185
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 895273
                            [last_modified] => 1453486290
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 904116
                            [last_modified] => 1453486052
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 899281
                            [last_modified] => 1453484508
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 861555
                            [last_modified] => 1453492549
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 878540
                            [last_modified] => 1453504940
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [no] => 885595
                            [last_modified] => 1453481124
                        )

                )

        )
```

**The problem** is when I loop the inner array, It skipped odd or even numbers, so didn't get all the data I need. Also, is there a more efficient way using foreach or another loops?

I can't wrap my head around this array structure, sorry for my lack of intelligence and written English. I appreciate the help and have a great day :).

Comment: why have two loops - one inside the other?

Comment: because I think to get to the thread numbers, I have to use : $json[$i]['threads'][$x]['no'];

so I can get : 
$json[0]['threads'][0]['no'];
 $json[0]['threads'][1]['no'];
 $json[0]['threads'][2]['no'];

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would work immediately - if you could provide the url of one of the source json files from 4chan that would help but hopefully this will help...

```
/* get the source json data and decode as an array ~ using `true` as 2nd argument */
$json=json_decode( file_get_contents('http://a.4cdn.org/wsg/threads.json'),true);

/* Not sure you need it but an array to store all the links generated */
$webmslinks=array();

/* Loop through the json array we created at the start */
foreach( $json as $thread ) {
    /* For each child array within data find the keyed element `threads` */
    $arr=$thread['threads'];


    /* Each `thread` is an array, we need to process these child arrays */
    foreach( $arr as $obj ){
        /* for convenience, convert to an object ( shorter notation )*/
        $data=(object)$obj;
        /* We need to know the `no` variable to build the link */
        $number=$data->no;
        $mod=$data->last_modified;/* not required */


        /* construct the url with the number of particular thread */
        $link='https://a.4cdn.org/wsg/thread/'.$number.'.json';
        $webmslinks[]=$link;

        /* display a link */
        echo "<a href='{$link}' target='_blank'>thread ".$number."</a><br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: here's the link to the json : http://a.4cdn.org/wsg/threads.json

btw, your code doesn't work, I try to encode the json as object using $json = json_decode($jsonfile); still not working. thanks

Comment: It worked, can you elaborate the process ? if not it's okay tho, I'm curious to how foreach works. btw, thanks man

Comment: @RadityaD: it may sound bit surprising, but there's such thing like documentation available: https://secure.php.net/foreach

Comment: @RamRaider : THANKS!!

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski: Thanks, im slow at using(or reading) the documentation, I can't find the specific problem im trying to solve, and sometimes the best way is to try it, but im going to stuck again in some point anyways :D. I love SO :D